# How can mock data in state in order to test a Redux reducer which deletes from the state?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, redux, jestjs

How can I add some test data to the state when testing a reducer in my ReactJS/Redux application?

I have this test case:

```
it("should store selected filter", () => {

    const selectedFilterData = { 
        id: 4321, 
        filterGroupId: 1234, 
        filterName: "gender", 
        text: "Male", 
        value: "pdl_profile_gender_1"
    }

    const action = { type: FILTER_SELECTED, data: selectedFilterData }

    Reducer(filters).expect(action).toReturnState({
        1234: {
            id: 1234,
            selectedFilters: [
                {
                    id: 4321,
                    filterName: "gender",
                    text: "Male",
                    value: "pdl_profile_gender_1"
                }
            ]
        }
    })
})
```

This action/reducer updates an existing 'selectedFilters' property for a corresponding ID. The above test is running when there is nothing in the state so throws an error. How can add test data in the state for that particular test case?

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using `redux-testkit`. According to the docs you can use `withState`. Here is an example.

```
Reducer(filters)
  .withState(state) // like this!
  .expect(action)
  .toReturnState(result);
```

https://github.com/wix/redux-testkit/blob/master/README.md